# A tool for using Spring Roo online?

Tags: spring-roo

I'd like to rapidly prototype a Java EE application. Starting from the design models, Spring Roo would help me by generating the CRUD artefacts. It is not installed in my team infrastructure.

Is there a web-based tool generating Spring Roo code from a high-level description (diagrams)?

Comment: There is no such tool that I know of.  However, you don't need to run Roo through an IDE, as it is a CLI app.  Also, I believe you can "code" the commands as a script and tell Roo to run them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach to this problem is for you to create your data model first.  If you want, you can do that online, using a tool from here:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957060/what-are-some-useful-online-database-modeling-applications

After you are happy with it and have it loaded into a local database, then you can use the database reverse engineering feature built into spring roo to generate an application.  For more details about that process, see the manual here:
   http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html